# A more pythonic way to map an object's method to a list of objects

Tags: python, object, methods, dictionary

Suppose I have a type of object called myObject which contains a method. I have a list containing a bunch of these objects and I want to run a method for all these objects. Right now I'm doing this by:

```
for object in list_of_objects:
    object.method()
```

I want to know if there's a more pythonic way of doing this; perhaps something like this:

```
map(lambda object:object.method(), list_of_objects)
```

I'd appreciate some insight on this. Thanks.

Comment: you means `map(lambda o: o.method, list_of_objects)`

Comment: First one is the best, why create a list in memory?

Comment: `object.method,`  should be `object.method()`  in map()

Comment: Both are different in first you don't creates any list(or say generator in Python3)  whereas in map() you do create. What is your objective??

Comment: I don't need the list at all. Actually the objects are threads and I'm trying to perform thread.start() on a list of threads.

Comment: The ordinary `for` loop is considered the best way. In Python 3, the `map` version breaks; the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists) specifically says to use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary In Python3 just map statement  even not calls function as it returns generator(not list) Am I correct?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes, you're correct. It returns a map object in Python3 , which is an iterator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First way is  correct if you need to just call method for each object.

```
for object in list_of_objects:
    object.method()
```

but suppose you want/need to create a list using returned values from the method then you should use either list-comprehension or `map()`.